# ActionScript 3.0 Preloader Issues

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

First off, I greatly appreciate any help, as always....

I have created a preloader from [Jarrod's Advanced AS3 Preloader Tutorail](http://www.portentinteractive.com/blog/advanced-actionscript-3-preloa.htm).  I searched elsewhere and this seemed like my best option as it was the only one I understood that did not require 2 SWF files.

My code is really in 2 classes, my **preloader** class and my **program** class. My problem is that the preloader is only loading the graphics that are in my flash and not actually initiating the program class. My question is *how do I get my preloading to initiate the program class?* The full code for both files are below.

**Preloader.as**

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.containers.ScrollPane;
    import flash.filters.*;

    public class Preloader extends MovieClip {
        public static  const ENTRY_FRAME:Number=3;
        public static  const DOCUMENT_CLASS:String='Program';
        public var myText:TextField;
        public var myFormat:TextFormat;
        private var progressBar:Sprite;
        private var progressText:TextField;
        public function Preloader() {

            stop();
            progressBar = getChildByName("loadbar_mc") as Sprite;
            progressText = getChildByName("loading_txt") as TextField;

            progressBar.scaleX = 0;

            myFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.font="Helvetica";
            myFormat.color = 0x000000;
            myFormat.size = 24;



            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
        }
        private function initHandler(event:Event):void {
            progressBar.scaleX = 0;
            progressText.text = "Loading 0%";

        }
        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            var loaded:uint = event.bytesLoaded;
            var total:uint = event.bytesTotal;

            var percentLoaded:Number = Math.round((loaded/total) * 50);
            progressBar.scaleX = loaded/total;
            progressText.text = "Loading " + percentLoaded + "%";

        }
        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            play();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

        }
        private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
            if (currentFrame >= Preloader.ENTRY_FRAME) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
                stop();
                main();

            }


        }
        private function errorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            myText.text = ("Sorry, there was an error. " + event);
            myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);


        }
        private function main():void {

            var programClass:Class = loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(Preloader.DOCUMENT_CLASS) as Class;
            var program:Sprite = new programClass() as Sprite;

            addChild(program);


        }

    }
}
```

**Program.as**

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.filters.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import fl.controls.TextInput;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.containers.ScrollPane;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import fl.controls.Label;



    public class Program extends Sprite {
        public function Program() {
            //define variable
            var startX:Number;
            var startY:Number;
            var counter:Number = 0;
            var intMessages:Number = 550;
            var limit:Number = 10;
            var intBoardSize:Number = 476*(Math.round(intMessages/15)+1);
            var intMessageMinX:Number = 35;
            var intMessageMaxX:Number = intBoardSize-99;
            var intMessageMinY:Number = 50;
            var intMessageMaxY:Number = 310;
            var activeGloveName:String = ""
            var intDegreeHigh:Number = 45;
            var intDegreeLow:Number = -45;
            var newGlove:mcGlove;

            //create objects
            var myGlove:mcGlove = new mcGlove();
            var showGlove:mcGlove = new mcGlove
            var mcglovetarget:mcGloveTarget = new mcGloveTarget();
            var myDropShadowFilterSmall = new DropShadowFilter (2,45,0x000000,0.65,3,3,2,3,false,false,false);
            var myDropShadowFilterDown = new DropShadowFilter (3,45,0x000000,0.65,5,5,2,3,false,false,false);
            var myDropShadowFilterUp = new DropShadowFilter (5,45,0x000000,0.65,7,7,2,3,false,false,false);
            var topShadow = new DropShadowFilter (3,90,0x000000,0.35,8,8,2,3,false,false,false);
            var pinkline:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var searchBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var txtSearchBox:TextInput = new TextInput();
            var sSearchBox_Label:String = "Go to glove #";
            var messageFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            var messageTextField:Label = new Label();
            var searchBoxLFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            var txtSearchBox_Label:TextField = new TextField();
            var SearchBoxBg:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var topShadowBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var searchButton:searchBtn = new searchBtn();
            var alertRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,848,393);
            var errorMessage:AlertBox = new AlertBox(alertRect);
            var holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            var aMessages:Array = new Array();

            //Create a glove for each message
            for (var gloveCount = 0; gloveCount < intMessages; gloveCount++){
                aMessages[gloveCount] = new mcGlove();
                aMessages[gloveCount] = createMessage(aMessages[gloveCount], gloveCount, gloveCount);
            }


            var scrollPane:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.verticalScrollPolicy = "false";
            scrollPane.move(374, 0);
            scrollPane.setSize(476, 370);
            scrollPane.horizontalLineScrollSize = 120;

            topShadowBox.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            topShadowBox.graphics.drawRect(0,0,870,5);
            topShadowBox.x = -10;
            topShadowBox.y = -5;
            topShadowBox.filters = [topShadow];

            pinkline.graphics.beginFill(0xDB9195);
            pinkline.graphics.drawRect(0,0,476,2);
            pinkline.x = 374;
            pinkline.y = 353;

            searchBox.graphics.beginFill(0xDB9195);
            searchBox.graphics.drawRect(0,0,476,25);
            searchBox.x = 374;
            searchBox.y = 370;

            SearchBoxBg.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
            SearchBoxBg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,35,17);
            SearchBoxBg.x = 475;
            SearchBoxBg.y = 374;

            txtSearchBox.width = 35;
            txtSearchBox.height = 15;
            txtSearchBox.move(475,375);
            txtSearchBox.restrict = "0-9";
            txtSearchBox.maxChars = 4;
            //txtSearchBox.background = "0xffffff";
            //txtSearchBox.border = "0x0xDB9195";

            searchBoxLFormat.font="Helvetica";
            searchBoxLFormat.color = 0xffffff;
            searchBoxLFormat.bold = true;
            searchBoxLFormat.size = 10;

            txtSearchBox_Label.x = 400;
            txtSearchBox_Label.y = 374;
            txtSearchBox_Label.width = 70;
            txtSearchBox_Label.height = 17;
            txtSearchBox_Label.text = sSearchBox_Label;
            txtSearchBox_Label.setTextFormat(searchBoxLFormat);

            searchButton.x = 534;
            searchButton.y = 382;

            //add to frame
            sortObjects();

            scrollPane.source = holder;         

            //create instance names for referancing/compairing objects
            myGlove.name = "mcglove";
            myGlove.setGloveMessage("My Sister Suzy, I pray that she will be ok. I love here so much, she is the best sister ever.  I miss you RIP");
            mcglovetarget.name = "mcglovetarget";

            messageFormat.font="Helvetica";
            messageFormat.color = 0xffffff;
            messageFormat.bold = true;
            messageFormat.size = 17;
            messageFormat.align = "center";

            messageTextField.x = -85;
            messageTextField.y = -40;
            messageTextField.width = 135;
            messageTextField.height = 140;
            messageTextField.text = myGlove.getGloveMessage();
            messageTextField.wordWrap = true;
            messageTextField.mouseEnabled = false;
            messageTextField.buttonMode = true;
            messageTextField.setStyle("textFormat", messageFormat);
            //messageTextField.hitArea = 0;
            myGlove.addChild(messageTextField);         

            //position the glove and modify apperiance
            myGlove.x = 163;
            myGlove.y = 211;
            myGlove.filters = [myDropShadowFilterDown];
            //myGlove.addChild(messageTextField);
            showGlove.x = 163;
            showGlove.y = 211;
            showGlove.filters = [myDropShadowFilterDown];
            mcglovetarget.x = 615;
            mcglovetarget.y = 211;
            mcglovetarget.alpha = 0

            //action listeners
            myGlove.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, selectGlove);
            myGlove.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseGlove);
            searchButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchMessages);
            txtSearchBox.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkForEnter);


            function selectGlove(event:MouseEvent):void {
                event.currentTarget.startDrag(true);
                var myTargetName:String = event.currentTarget.name + "target";
                var myTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(myTargetName);
                myGlove.filters = [myDropShadowFilterUp];
                addChild(myTarget);
                event.currentTarget.parent.addChild(event.currentTarget);
                addChild(topShadowBox);
                myTarget.alpha = .5;
                startX = event.currentTarget.x;
                startY = event.currentTarget.y;
            }

            function releaseGlove(event:MouseEvent):void {
                event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
                var myTargetName:String = event.currentTarget.name + "target";
                var myTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(myTargetName);
                event.currentTarget.filters = [myDropShadowFilterDown];
                myTarget.alpha = 0;

                if (event.currentTarget.dropTarget != null && event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent == myTarget){
                    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, selectGlove);
                    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseGlove);
                    event.currentTarget.x = myTarget.x;
                    event.currentTarget.y = myTarget.y;
                    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name), "scaleX",Strong.easeOut,getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).scaleX,.28,2,true);
                    var myTween2:Tween = new Tween(getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name), "scaleY",Strong.easeOut,getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).scaleY,.28,2,true);
                    holder.addChild(getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name));
                    event.currentTarget.removeChild(messageTextField);
                    scrollPane.source = holder;
                    holder.getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).x=Math.round(Math.random() * (470+Math.round(scrollPane.horizontalScrollPosition) - Math.round(scrollPane.horizontalScrollPosition))) + Math.round(scrollPane.horizontalScrollPosition);
                    holder.getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).y=Math.round(Math.random() * (intMessageMaxY - intMessageMinY)) + intMessageMinY;
                    holder.getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickMessage);
                    holder.getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseMessage);
                    event.currentTarget.name = "" + intMessages;
                    addChild(showGlove);
                    messageTextField.text = "Select a glove to view its message here.";
                    showGlove.addChild(messageTextField);
                } else {
                    event.currentTarget.x = startX;
                    event.currentTarget.y = startY;
                }

                //sortObjects();
                addChild(mcglovetarget);
                addChild(scrollPane);
                addChild(pinkline);
                addChild(searchBox);
                addChild(SearchBoxBg);
                addChild(txtSearchBox);
                addChild(txtSearchBox_Label);
                addChild(searchButton);
                addChild(topShadowBox);
            }

            function position(target) {
                target.x = Math.round(Math.random() * (intMessageMaxX - intMessageMinX)) + intMessageMinX;
                target.y = Math.round(Math.random() * (intMessageMaxY - intMessageMinY)) + intMessageMinY;
                for (var i:uint=0; i<aMessages.length -1 ; i++) {
                    if(target.hitTestObject(aMessages[i]) && counter < limit){
                        counter++;
                        position(target);
                        //return false;
                    };
                }
            } 

            function createMessage(newGlove:mcGlove, sName:String, sMessage:String){
                newGlove.scaleX = .28;
                newGlove.scaleY = .28;
                counter = 0;
                position(newGlove);
                newGlove.rotation = (0, 0, 0, Math.round(Math.random() * (intDegreeHigh - intDegreeLow)) + intDegreeLow);
                newGlove.filters = [myDropShadowFilterSmall];
                newGlove.name = sName;
                holder.addChild(newGlove);
                newGlove.setGloveMessage(sMessage);
                newGlove.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickMessage);
                newGlove.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseMessage);
                newGlove.buttonMode = true;
                return newGlove;
            }

            function clickMessage(event:MouseEvent):void{
                selectMessage(event.target);
            }

            function checkForEnter(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) // If Keypress is Enter
                {
                    searchMessages();
                }
            }


            function searchMessages():void{
                if (showGlove.parent == mcglovetarget.parent){
                    if ( txtSearchBox.text != "" ){
                        var searchTarget:DisplayObject = holder.getChildByName(txtSearchBox.text);
                        if (searchTarget){
                            selectMessage(searchTarget);
                            scrollPane.horizontalScrollPosition = searchTarget.x - 220;
                        }else if(1==1){ //if in file
                            gloveCount = aMessages.length;
                            aMessages[gloveCount] = new mcGlove();
                            aMessages[gloveCount] = createMessage(aMessages[gloveCount], txtSearchBox.text, txtSearchBox.text);
                            selectMessage(aMessages[gloveCount]);
                            scrollPane.horizontalScrollPosition = aMessages[gloveCount].x - 220;
                        }else{
                            errorMessage.setAlertText("Sorry, the glove you are searching for does not exist.");
                            addChild(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    errorMessage.setAlertText("You must post your message first, otherwise your message will be lost.");
                    addChild(errorMessage);
                }
            }

            function selectMessage(object:mcGlove):void{
                if (showGlove.parent == mcglovetarget.parent){
                    if (activeGloveName != ""){
                        var activeGlove:DisplayObject = holder.getChildByName(activeGloveName);
                        activeGlove.filters = [myDropShadowFilterSmall];
                        activeGlove.scaleX = .28;
                        activeGlove.scaleY = .28;
                        holder.addChild(activeGlove);
                    }
                    activeGloveName = object.name;
                    //event.target.dragIt();
                    holder.addChild(object);
                    object.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xABEEFC, .65, 15, 15, 1, 1, false, false)];
                    object.scaleX = .35;
                    object.scaleY = .35;
                    messageTextField.text = object.getGloveMessage();
                }else{
                    errorMessage.setAlertText("You must post your message first, otherwise your message will be lost.");
                    addChild(errorMessage);
                }
            }

            function releaseMessage(event:MouseEvent):void{
                event.target.dropIt();
            }



            function sortObjects():void{
                addChild(mcglovetarget);
                addChild(scrollPane);
                addChild(pinkline);
                addChild(searchBox);
                addChild(SearchBoxBg);
                addChild(txtSearchBox);
                addChild(txtSearchBox_Label);
                addChild(searchButton);
                addChild(myGlove);
                addChild(topShadowBox);
            }

            myGlove.buttonMode = true;
            searchButton.buttonMode = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the preloader main, you istantiate the program like this

```
var program:Sprite = new programClass() as Sprite;
```

I think you should do:

```
var program:Sprite = new Program();
```

Note that you don't need to cast Program as a Sprite, since it is already a Sprite.
ps: are you really writing nested functions in the Program constructor? omg :-/

Comment: I think it should be "var program:programClass = new programClass()". No need to involve Sprite at all.